# Find the missing initial conditions for system of ODES

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following system of ODEs:

```
   s1` (t) = -(k1*s1 *(k2*s2 + s3))/m,
   s2` (t) = ((k1*s1 *(k2*s2 + s3))/m) - k3*s2,
    s3' (t) = k3*s2 - k4*s3
     s4' (t) = k4*s3
```

where k1=0.4029;k2=0.7;k3=0.41;k4=0.182; m=s1+s2+s3+s4;

I used:

```
    k1 = 0.4029; k2 = 0.78; k3 = 0.41; k4 = 0.182; m = s1+s2+s3+s4;

    u3[s1, s2, s3, 
    s4] = {s1, s2, s3, s4} /. 
    First@DSolve[{s1'[t] == -(k1*s1[t]*(k2*s2[t] + s3[t]))/m, 
     s2'[t] == ((k1*s1[t]*(k2*s2[t] + s3[t]))/m) - k3*s2[t], 
    s3'[t] == k3*s2[t] - k4*s3[t], s4'[t] == k4*s3[t]}, {s1, s2, s3,
     s4}, t] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2, C[3] -> c3, C[4] -> c4}
```

But it is not working, any help?

1) I need numerical solution for the system.

2) If possible can we get analytic solution or approximate solutions for each unknown functions si, i=1..4, given in a polynomials?
Thanks

Comment: You try to reinvent a SEIR-model? The initial conditions aren't unique, you need more information .

Comment: Dear Ulrich, what type of information should I have?

Comment: The initial conditions! Or if you know the solution (measurement) you could try to find the optimal initial conditions .

Comment: Dear, I do not have the I.C which my mean post questions, there is no exact solution!! so I can find I.C?

Comment: If Mathematica could solve your ode without i.c. the solution would depend on several free parameters! These parameters usually are adjusted by additional conditions.

Comment: You normally find the initial conditions in the problem you are solving. If the problem is to find the (general) solution to the ODE above, then you can let the initial conditions be arbitrary and try to find a symbolic solution. If you must use a numerical solver (because, say, `DSolve` fails), which seems to be the case here, then you write a numerical function in which the initial conditions are variable parameters of the function.  `ParametricNDSolve` was added to Mathematica to facilitate this type of problem.

Comment: Dear Michael, do you mean I assume s1(0)=r1; s2(0)=r2;s3(0)=r3 and s4(0)=r4, where ri, i=1...4, unknown? then what shall I do?

Comment: It all depends on what question you want to address with this model.  Do you want to project forward in time?  Then you'll need to supply initial conditions (either from data or make up reasonable ones).  Do you want to infer the initial conditions (an inverse problem)?  Then you'll need some time series data and could search numerically for the initial conditions that best fit.

Comment: I want to get the values of s1,s2,s3,s4 either analytically or numerically.

Comment: @user62716 Which do you want, `si(0)` or `si(t)` for `t>0`? If you want `si(t)` for `t>0`, then you need to add initial conditions.  If you want `si(0)`, then you need some `si(t)` for `t>0`.

Comment: Dear Chris, I want si(t), t>0, but I do not have si(0)?

Comment: @user62716 Then just make up some plausible initial conditions.  Maybe `s1[0]==n-0.001`, `s2[0]==0.001`, `s3[0]==s4[0]==0` is interesting.  BTW, don't use `N`, it's a built-in function.

Comment: Thanks Chris I will try.

Comment: Dear Nasser, I have tried 2x2 system is working        u2[y, z] = {y, z} /. 
   First@DSolve[{y'[x] == x^2 y[x], z'[x] == 5 z[x]}, {y, z}, 
     x] /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}

Comment: But for 4x4 my system not??

Comment: Yes, but if you try the ODE's you show, using NDSolve, you'll see they give zero solution for any IC or any values.

Comment: Can you send me the NDSolve line code

Comment: OK, fixed it. I copied one wrong. Will post answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me show how to get an asymptotic polynomial solution at least for small t.

```
k1 = 0.4029; k2 = 0.78; k3 = 0.41; k4 = 0.182; 
m = s1[t] + s2[t] + s3[t] + s4[t];

eqs = {s1'[t] == -(k1*s1[t]*(k2*s2[t] + s3[t]))/m, 
       s2'[t] == ((k1*s1[t]*(k2*s2[t] + s3[t]))/m) - k3*s2[t], 
       s3'[t] == k3*s2[t] - k4*s3[t], s4'[t] == k4*s3[t], 
       s1[0] == 3.9, s2[0] == 8.5, s3[0] == 3.7, s4[0] == 0.8} // 
Simplify
```

Now define the si as general polynoms, here up to order 6 and then solve for all the prefactors of powers of t.

```
{s1[t_] = Sum[a[1][s] t^s, {s, 0, 6}] + O[t]^7, 
 s2[t_] = Sum[a[2][s] t^s, {s, 0, 6}] + O[t]^7, 
 s3[t_] = Sum[a[3][s] t^s, {s, 0, 6}] + O[t]^7, 
 s4[t_] = Sum[a[4][s] t^s, {s, 0, 6}] + O[t]^7};

le = LogicalExpand[#] & /@ eqs;

sol1 = NSolve[And @@ le, 
        Flatten[Table[a[j][s], {s, 0, 6}, {j, 1, 4}], 1]];

{ss1[t_], ss2[t_], ss3[t_], ss4[t_]} = 
   Normal[{s1[t], s2[t], s3[t], s4[t]} /. First@sol1] // Simplify;

{ss1[t], ss2[t], ss3[t], ss4[t]} // TableForm

(*   {3.9\[VeryThinSpace]- 0.960452 t + 0.0791007 t^2 + 0.013307 t^3 - 0.00484174 t^4 + 0.000626304 t^5 - 0.0000156141 t^6, 

      8.5\[VeryThinSpace]- 2.52455 t + 0.438432 t^2 - 0.073226 t^3 + 0.0123474 t^4 - 0.00163879 t^5 + 0.000127598 t^6, 

      3.7\[VeryThinSpace]+ 2.8116 t - 0.773388 t^2 + 0.106838 t^3 - 0.0123668 t^4 + 0.00146264 t^5 - 0.000156351 t^6, 
      0.8\[VeryThinSpace]+ 0.6734 t + 0.255856 t^2 - 0.0469189 t^3 + 0.00486112 t^4 - 0.000450151 t^5 + 0.0000443667 t^6}   *)
```

For comparison., i take the point data @Nasser provided. It shows, this polynomial aproximation is good for small t. Solving for higher order of polynoms however quickly needs very long calculation time of NSolve. Solving for arbitrary parameters with Solve to higher orders is nearly not practicable.

```
(*   tp=Transpose[  point data of @Nasser];   *)

tp2 = Transpose[{Range[0, 20, 1], #}] & /@ tp;

lp = ListPlot[tp2, PlotStyle -> {Black, Cyan, Red, Blue}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 9}}];

pl = Plot[Evaluate[{ss1[t], ss2[t], ss3[t], ss4[t]}], {t, 0, 6}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Black, Cyan, Red, Blue}];

Show[pl, lp]
```

[image]

**Edit**   How to determine any kind of error

Since in most cases you do not know the exact solution, you can test, how close to zero is left minus right side of all equations for all t.  ( lhs-rhs is zero with exact solution)

First clear the  polynom definitions of si in order to go back to the original equation and then substitute the found solutions i called ssi.

```
{ss1[t_], ss2[t_], ss3[t_], ss4[t_]} = 
Normal[{s1[t], s2[t], s3[t], s4[t]} /. First@sol5] // Simplify

Clear[s1, s2, s3, s4]

plorder5 = 
  Plot[Evaluate[
   eqs[[All, 1]] - eqs[[All, 2]] /. {s1 -> ss1, s2 -> ss2, s3 -> ss3, 
 s4 -> ss4}], {t, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> .2]
```

[image]

At order 7 error is smaller than with order 5. But be aware, this is not the error of found solutions (which is normally smaller as you see), but the error of the differential equations.

```
{ss1[t_], ss2[t_], ss3[t_], ss4[t_]} = 
Normal[{s1[t], s2[t], s3[t], s4[t]} /. First@sol7] // Simplify

Clear[s1, s2, s3, s4]

plorder7 = 
   Plot[Evaluate[
eqs[[All, 1]] - eqs[[All, 2]] /. {s1 -> ss1, s2 -> ss2, s3 -> ss3, 
 s4 -> ss4}], {t, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> .2]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Akku14, many thanks for the above approximate solution...Best regards

Comment: Dear Akku14, can we evaluate the error (say relative error, or any type of error) for different order say 2,3,4..6 and plot it to see if the errors decrease when we increase the order?of course with fixed Nasser results(we consider Nasser results as the exact solution)?..Best regards.

Comment: Dear Akku14, the above code should be add at the end of previous code? or shall we re-arrange it order 5 and 7? as the original code at order 6?

Comment: You took t=0 to 6?for both order 5 and 7? is it correct?

Answer (score 4):

> Can you send me the NDSolve line code

Updated for the new constraint just added to the question which was not there before, which is `m=s1+s2+s3+s4`. Where `m` here is total population.

I tried to use DAE to add this to the system of ode's. But it turned out this is not needed.

All what is needed is to set `m` to be the the sum of `s1+s2+s3+s4` at time zero, then this constraint is automatically satisfied for all time.

So modified the code a little to remove `m` as variable using slider, and set it internally.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, s1, s2, s3, s4, t, ic, sys, m,data},

  m = s10 + s20 + s30 + s40;
  ode1 = s1'[t] == -(k1*s1[t]*(k2*s2[t] + s3[t]))/m;
  ode2 = s2'[t] == ((k1*s1[t]*(k2*s2[t] + s3[t]))/m) - k3*s2[t];
  ode3 = s3'[t] == k3*s2[t] - k4*s3[t];
  ode4 = s4'[t] == k4*s3[t];

  sys = {ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4};

  ic = {s1[0] == s10, s2[0] == s20, s3[0] == s30, s4[0] == s40};
  {s1, s2, s3, s4} = 
   Quiet@NDSolveValue[{ode1, ode2, ode3, ode4, ic}, {s1, s2, s3, 
      s4}, {t, 0, tMax}];

  data = Table[{s1[i], s2[i], s3[i], s4[i]}, {i, 0, tMax, 1}];
  Print[data];

  Plot[
   {s1[t], s2[t], s3[t], s4[t], m[t]}, {t, 0, tMax},
   PlotLegends -> {"s1  susceptible", 
     "s2 exposed but not yet infectious", "s3 Infected", 
     "s4 Recovered"},
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 20}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
   ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> 20,
   PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"SEIR infection model"}], Bold, 14],
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Cyan, Red, Blue}
   ]

  ],
 {{s10, 3.9, "susceptible s1(0)"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{s20, 8.5, "exposed but not yet infectious s2(0)"}, 0, 10, .1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{s30, 3.7, "Infected s3(0)"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{s40, 0.8, "Recovered s4(0)"}, 0, 10, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k1, 0.4029, "k1"}, 0, 1, .0001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k2, 0.78, "k2"}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k3, 0.41, "k3"}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{k4, 0.182, "k4"}, 0, 1, .001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{tMax, 20, "time?"}, 1, 100, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {s10, s20, s30, s40, k1, k2, k3, k4, tMax}
 ]
```

Prints s1,s2,s3,s4 for the time used at intervals selected in code above

```
{{3.9, 8.5, 3.7, 0.8}, {3.02772, 6.35149, 5.834, 1.68679}, {2.34279, 
  4.77191, 6.92468, 2.86063}, {1.82802, 3.58489, 7.3216, 
  4.16549}, {1.44877, 2.68696, 7.2659, 5.49837}, {1.17086, 2.00878, 
  6.92715, 6.79321}, {0.966539, 1.49902, 6.42446, 8.00998}, {0.815065,
   1.11785, 5.84026, 9.12682}, {0.701542, 0.834097, 5.23006, 
  10.1343}, {0.615442, 0.623534, 4.62983, 11.0312}, {0.549355, 
  0.467548, 4.06158, 11.8215}, {0.498045, 0.352027, 3.53761, 
  12.5123}, {0.457782, 0.266386, 3.06359, 13.1122}, {0.425883, 
  0.202753, 2.64079, 13.6306}, {0.400392, 0.155313, 2.26778, 
  14.0765}, {0.379865, 0.119791, 1.94147, 14.4589}, {0.363226, 
  0.0930537, 1.65792, 14.7858}, {0.349659, 0.0728083, 1.41284, 
  15.0647}, {0.338543, 0.0573777, 1.20193, 15.3022}, {0.329394, 
  0.0455346, 1.02105, 15.504}, {0.321838, 0.0363782, 0.86638, 
  15.6754}}
```

Comment: Great expert, please can we get approximate solution, not numerical, i.e. for example s1= function,...etc

Comment: Dear Nasser, also m in fact equal to s1+s2+s3+s4

Comment: @user62716 please add this to your question as it was not there. This makes the system a DAE and I need to update my answer in this case.

Comment: Many thanks for helping me Dr.Nasser, I have updated my questions

Comment: @user62716 updated for `m=s1+s2+s3+s4` For your question: `DSolve` can not solve this analytically, so only numerical solution is possible.

Comment: Many thanks Dr.Nasser, in your opinion can we get approximate solutions for the system in known elementary functions or polynomials?

Comment: what about AsymptoticDSolveValue? thanks

Comment: @user62716 I also tried `AsymptoticDSolveValue` but it was not giving an answer after sometime so I stopped it. I think numerical solution is your only hope for this.

Comment: Great Dr. Nasser, I am really sorry took to much time from you, final things, can we got a numerical table for Si, i,...4, on some interval?

Comment: @user62716 Yes, you can just for now use Print statement. Later on, you can improve this more, may be save the data to a file, etc... added print to the code above.

Comment: Many thanks Dr.Nasser, I am more than happy to know great expert like you, I hope can get contact details of you to do collaborate researches.  Best regatds